# How to notify a change from a class to multiple ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm writing because I'd like to know what's the best method to notify a change from a class to multiple ViewControllers. At the moment I'm using delegate method but I'm sure It's not the best one for this purpose. I created a class where I receive data and after a bit of processing I need to send the processed message to some ViewControllers (any one shows a piece of that message.). At the moment I have a singleton for the class and I assign its delegate to a different ViewController when I load it through a menu. What's your suggestion to do this job?

Here is an example of my actual code:

```
import Foundation

protocol MyClassDelegate {

  func receivedData(_ sender: MyClass)

}

class MyClass: NSObject {

  // create the var for delegate
  var delegate: MyClassDelegate?

  // save the single instance
  static private var instance: MyClass {
    return sharedInstance
  }

  private let sharedInstance = MyClass()


  static func getInstance() -> MyClass {
    return instance
  }

  func processData() {

    // at the end of the process
    delegate?.receivedData(self)
  }

}


class Menu: UIViewController {

  private var containerView: UIView!

  private let myClass = Myclass.getInstance()

  private var vcOne = VcOne()
  private var vcTwo = VcTwo()


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    containerView = UIVIew()
    // set containerView position and dimensions
  }

  func selectViewController(previous: UIViewController, next: UIViewController) {

    // remove actual loaded ViewController
    previous.willMove(toParent: nil)
    previous.view.removeFromSuperView()
    previous.removeFromParent()


    // assign the delegate
    myClass.delegate = next

    // add the new ViewController
    self.addChild(next)
    slef.addSubView(next.view)
    next.didMove(toParent: self)
  }

}


class VcOne: UIViewController, MyClassDelegate {

  func receivedData(_ sender: MyClass) {
    // data received
  }
}

class VcTwo: UIViewController, MyClassDelegate {


  func receivedData(_ sender: MyClass) {
    // data received
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NotificationCenter https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter to broadcast a message. or use KVO. Generally I consider notification center much easier.

simple example:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-post-messages-using-notificationcenter

Comment: Thank you. Notification center works fine for my scope.